# PECL OAuth 1.2.3 for PHP 5.6 on CentOS 6

Tags: php, linux, oauth, centos, pecl

My Set up:

- CentOS 6
- PHP 5.6.30
- EasyApache 3.34.11 (Configured using cPanel & WHM)
- Apache 2.4.25
- MySQL 5.5.52

I am currently attempting to get Oauth 1.2.3 installed (In order to use the Quickbooks Online API) on my installation but am running into problems attempting to get it installed.

I ran:

```
cd /usr/local
curl -OL https://pecl.php.net/get/oauth-1.2.3.tgz
tar xvzf oauth-1.2.3.tgz
cd oauth-1.2.3
phpize
./configure
make
```

And get:

```
root@mywebsite [/usr/local/oauth-1.2.3]# phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20131106
Zend Module Api No:      20131226
Zend Extension Api No:   220131226

root@mywebsite [/usr/local/oauth-1.2.3]# ./configure
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr/local
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/local/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for oauth support... yes, shared
checking for cURL in default path... cURL not found
checking for ld used by cc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for BSD-compatible nm... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking dlfcn.h usability... yes
checking dlfcn.h presence... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1966080
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from cc object... ok
checking for objdir... .libs
checking for ar... ar
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for strip... strip
checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fPIC
checking if cc PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
checking if cc static flag -static works... yes
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking whether the cc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no

creating libtool
appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h

root@mywebsite [/usr/local/oauth-1.2.3]# make
/bin/sh /usr/local/oauth-1.2.3/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/usr/local/oauth-1.2.3 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/usr/local/oauth-1.2.3/include -I/usr/local/oauth-1.2.3/main -I/usr/local/oauth-1.2.3 -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2 -Wall -g   -c /usr/local/oauth-1.2.3/oauth.c -o oauth.lo 
mkdir .libs
 cc -I. -I/usr/local/oauth-1.2.3 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/usr/local/oauth-1.2.3/include -I/usr/local/oauth-1.2.3/main -I/usr/local/oauth-1.2.3 -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -Wall -g -c /usr/local/oauth-1.2.3/oauth.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/oauth.o
In file included from /usr/local/oauth-1.2.3/php_oauth.h:47,
                 from /usr/local/oauth-1.2.3/oauth.c:14:
/usr/local/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:29:18: error: pcre.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /usr/local/oauth-1.2.3/php_oauth.h:47,
                 from /usr/local/oauth-1.2.3/oauth.c:14:
/usr/local/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:37: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/local/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:38: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/local/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:44: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘pcre’
/usr/local/oauth-1.2.3/oauth.c: In function ‘oauth_compare_key’:
/usr/local/oauth-1.2.3/oauth.c:507: warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type
/usr/local/oauth-1.2.3/oauth.c:516: warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type
make: *** [oauth.lo] Error 1
```

I found this question where they said the Perl 5 Compatible Regular Expression Library wasn't installed: [Attempting to install OAuth on Ubuntu but getting errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22772854/attempting-to-install-oauth-on-ubuntu-but-getting-errors), but after running `yum install pcre.x86_64`, it said `Package pcre-7.8-7.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version`. So that isn't the problem.

[PECL OAuth for PHP 5.3 on CentOS 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683884/pecl-oauth-for-php-5-3-on-centos-5) didn't solve my issue either as I am running the most up to date versions of PHP and MySQL.

When I went into WHM, I only saw version 2.0.2 available under Software -> Module Installers -> PHP Pecl -> Manage -> oauth (2.0.2). However, according to the [PECL Website](http://pecl.php.net/package/oauth/2.0.2), this version only works with PHP 7.0.0 or newer. I am using 5.6.30 on this server. And my hosting provider (whom I pay for managed support through) has stated they cannot help me because they cannot guarantee that installing Oauth 1.2.3 will not break cPanel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem:

I was lacking the `pcre-devel` package which is required for Oauth to be installed.